# Batch put's - ensure store.subscribe is not updated till all put's done

Tags: redux-saga

I have to do two puts. The render both strongly depend on each other. Meaning the first put has to happen at same time as second. Currently, every `put` I do causes a re-render of the related components.  Same time means, the `store.subscribe` must not be triggered until both `put`'s happen. I can create a specific action for this, but I was wondering if there was a way to batch put's. I tried `put.resolve` and the also the following:

```
yield all([
    put(updateEntity(ENTITYS.COMMENT, id, comment)),
    put(updateEntity(ENTITYS.STORY, storyId, entity => ({ commentIds:entity.commentIds.map(commentId => commentId === id ? comment.id : commentId) })))
]);
```

But this didn't work, the `store.subscribe` is being triggered after each `put`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) for this.

After setting up you just go.

```
import { batchActions } from 'redux-batched-actions';

yield put(batchActions([
  updateEntity(ENTITYS.COMMENT, id, comment),
  updateEntity(ENTITYS.STORY, storyId, entity => ({ commentIds:entity.commentIds.map(commentId => commentId === id ? comment.id : commentId) })),
]))
```

Comment: Is there anything built in, like `put.resolve`? Thank very much sir for your reply I was waiting for a bit.

Comment: Thanks very much for your support on github. I am going to try `redux-batch` - https://github.com/manaflair/redux-batch - before I try redux-batched-actions, it seems simpler in that I can just `put` arrays.

Comment: I'm linking the Github issue for posterity - https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1161

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what needs to be achieved, maybe it is enough to throttle notifications to subscribers and/or marking certain actions as passive (state-only - not causing notifications). If that would be the case - you can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-notification-enhancer